# "Collapsible" <div>

Tags: html, css, visible

I'm having some trouble with a  that I'm trying to keep hidden, until the user clicks on a  element.

The HTML looks like:

```
<h3 class="filter-type">BRAND</h3>
<div class="sidebarlistscroll">
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.filter-type {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
}

.sidebarlistscroll {
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.filter-type:active .sidebarlistscroll {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I've also tried using :focus and :hover subclasses but still it won't work, the div stays hidden no matter what.

I'm trying to achieve this without using javascript if possible.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your **sidebarlistscroll** DIV come after the **H3** not inside **H3**. Write like this:

```
.filter-type:active + .sidebarlistscroll {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

If you want the div to remain visible after when you stopped clicking on it. Then you have to do some changes in your code. Write like this :

```
<label class="filter-type" for="filter">BRAND</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="filter">
<div class="sidebarlistscroll">
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.filter-type {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
}

.sidebarlistscroll {
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filter{display:none}
#filter:checked + .sidebarlistscroll{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/BU4Qt/

Comment: Thanks, that worked... But I now see that my code doesn't do what I need it to. I need the div to remain visible after I've stopped clicking on it. Any advice on how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want...?

Style:

```
.filter-type {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
 }
```

HTML :

```
 <h3 class="filter-type">BRAND</h3>
 <p onclick="this.innerHTML='<div><ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul></div>'">Click Here</p>
```